# How do I get or set the position of an image on a Silverlight Canvas control

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have an Image control as the child of a Canvas control. If I load the Image control with a bitmap and set the Stretch property to Uniform, I get a centered image.  However, I can find no way to either set or retrieve the position of the Image.  Solution anyone?

Here is some code to make understanding the problem a bit easier:

```
Image img = new Image();
img.Height = maxSize.Height;
img.Width = maxSize.Width;
img.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
img.Source = bmp;
myCanvas.Children.Add(img);

// returns 0:
MessageBox.Show(((Image)myCanvas.Children[0]).GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty).ToString());
MessageBox.Show(((Image)myCanvas.Children[0]).GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty).ToString());

// in order to set explicitly set the values I have to know what they are?
Double left = {the current left value};
Double top = {the current top value};
((Image)myCanvas.Children[0]).SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, left);
((Image)myCanvas.Children[0]).SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, top);`
```

I select the code and press the {} button, but it does not work for me, neither does entering code ticks manually.

Comment: It's not entirely clear *what* you are trying to accomplish. You are reading the left/top values...and then writing them back without changing them. You are also confused as to why they are 0. The best I can guess is that you are confusing the position of the image *control* with the apparent position of the picture *inside* the image control. The left/top position of the *picture* inside the control is determined by (ImageControlDimension - ScaledPictureSize) / 2. Maybe if you explain what you want to do with the left/top property, we can tell you how to get the property you really need.

Comment: I need to know the actual location of my picture inside the image control.  I can find no reference to the ImageControlDimension and ScaledPictureSize via Google.  What I am trying to acomplish is just to draw a rectangle over a portion of the image and then extract that portion of the image.  I can do this quite easily if the image (or picture in the image control) left top is 0,0, but if not then I need to know what it is.  I can't believe it's so difficult to find this out.

Comment: Sorry for bumping a 4 year old question, but did you find a solution to this? I'm facing pretty much exactly the same problem and can't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Canvas.LeftProperty and Canvas.TopProperty

```
var left = (double)image.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)
left += 50;
image.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, left);
```

Comment: This is not the answer.  It returns 0 unless explicitly set first.  I have solved the problem in other contexts by explicitly setting the value, for example by drawing a rectangle using the mouse, and then explicitly setting the values using the mouse coordinates used to draw the rectangle.  However, in this case I do not know what the cooridinates are so I cannot explicitly set them.